# Align formules on more than 1 position

Tags: align, formulas

```
\begin{align*}  
    I\sub{D} &= 0 \hspace{1cm} \text{wanneer} \hspace{1cm} V\sub{GS} = V\sub{GS(off)} \\
    I\sub{D} &= \frac{I\sub{DSS}}{4}\hspace{0.5cm} \text{wanneer} \hspace{1cm}V\sub{GS} = 0.5V\sub{GS(off)}, \\  
    I\sub{D} &= \frac{I\sub{DSS}}{2} \hspace{0.5cm}\text{wanneer}\hspace{1cm} V\sub{GS} = 0.3V\sub{GS(off)},\\  
    \text{en   } I\sub{D} &= I\sub{DSS} \hspace{0.5cm}\text{wanneer} \hspace{1cm}V\sub{GS} = 0.   
\end{align*}
```

`{S:\sub{D}` is a macro to easily have the subscripts in Roman iso italics.

[image]

the first "="signs are nicely aligned, but I'd also like to align the "wanneer" and the second "=" signs. Is that possible? I tried adding a second "&" but that did not work

Answer (score 1):

You may use `alignat`, but I believe that `dcases` is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  I\sub{D} &= 0 &&\quad\text{wanneer}\quad & V\sub{GS} &= V\sub{GS(off)} \\
  I\sub{D} &= \frac{I\sub{DSS}}{4} &&\quad\text{wanneer}\quad & V\sub{GS} &= 0.5V\sub{GS(off)}, \\
  I\sub{D} &= \frac{I\sub{DSS}}{2} &&\quad\text{wanneer}\quad & V\sub{GS} &= 0.3V\sub{GS(off)}, \\
  \text{en } I\sub{D} &= I\sub{DSS} &&\quad\text{wanneer}\quad & V\sub{GS} &= 0.
\end{alignat*}

\[
I\sub{D}=
\begin{dcases}
0 &\text{wanneer}\quad V\sub{GS} = V\sub{GS(off)}, \\
\frac{I\sub{DSS}}{4} &\text{wanneer}\quad V\sub{GS} = 0.5V\sub{GS(off)}, \\
\frac{I\sub{DSS}}{2} &\text{wanneer}\quad V\sub{GS} = 0.3V\sub{GS(off)}, \\
I\sub{DSS} &\text{wanneer}\quad V\sub{GS} = 0.
\end{dcases}
\]

\[
I\sub{D}=
\begin{dcases}
0 & V\sub{GS} = V\sub{GS(off)}, \\
\frac{I\sub{DSS}}{4} & V\sub{GS} = 0.5V\sub{GS(off)}, \\
\frac{I\sub{DSS}}{2} & V\sub{GS} = 0.3V\sub{GS(off)}, \\
I\sub{DSS} & V\sub{GS} = 0.
\end{dcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally, I'd go with the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you employ an `alignat*` environment, which allows finer control over horizontal spacing than does the `align*` environment. Alternatively, you could provide some explicit visual grouping by using a couple of `cases` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel} % 'wanneer' = "whenever", right?
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat*' and 'cases' environments 
\newcommand\sub[1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}} % is this correct?

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    I\sub{D} &= 0                       &\quad \text{wanneer}\quad  V\sub{GS} &= V\sub{GS(off)}  \\
    I\sub{D} &= \tfrac{1}{4}I\sub{DSS}  &\quad \text{wanneer}\quad  V\sub{GS} &= 0.5V\sub{GS(off)}, \\  
    I\sub{D} &= \tfrac{1}{2}I\sub{DSS}  &\quad \text{wanneer}\quad  V\sub{GS} &= 0.3V\sub{GS(off)}, \\  
\text{en } I\sub{D} &= I\sub{DSS}       &\quad \text{wanneer}\quad  V\sub{GS} &= 0.   
\end{alignat*}

\[
    I\sub{D} = \begin{cases} 
      0 \\ 
      0.25I\sub{DSS} \\ 
      0.5I\sub{DSS} \\
      I\sub{DSS}
    \end{cases}
    \text{wanneer}\quad  
    V\sub{GS} = \begin{cases}
       V\sub{GS(off)}  \\
       0.5V\sub{GS(off)} \\
       0.3V\sub{GS(off)} \\
       0
    \end{cases} \!\!. 
\]

\end{document}
```